# Using Dask to read multiple datasets and factor the class column

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, dask

I have 50 csv files makes 14.8 gb total. I converted all data to parquet files. Each file is sensor data that has millions of rows collected from patients. I have to make multi-class classification, I have 5 classes. I have 20 columns including class, My task is to group the data by class and then separate it into 6000 rows of datas. That is, to make data such as 6000x19 image datas. And to train in CNN model using TensorFlow Keras. I am reading data using pandas i am reading 4 file and appending them to an empty pandas dataframe.

But I am getting ram error when I am trying to read more than 4 datasets using pandas. I am searching for how to read more files on the internet for weeks but I didn't figure it out. Many people suggest Dask.

This is how I do it using pandas

```
data_dir = r'/content/drive/MyDrive/uyku_parquet'
files = ['1', '2', '3', '5'] 
data = pd.DataFrame()
for file in files:
   df = pd.read_parquet(data_dir+'/'+file+'.parquet')
   data = data.append(df)
   del df
```

this is how i am trying to do it using Dask

```
data_dir = r'/content/drive/MyDrive/uyku_parquet'
data = dd.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame(), npartitions=5)

files = ['1', '2', '3', '5','37','19','47','35']  
for file in files:
  df = dd.read_parquet(data_dir+'/'+file+'.parquet')
  data = data.append(df)
  del df
```

Until now there is no error but i need to factorize my column. This is how i am doing it using Pandas.

```
siniflar_kodlanmamis = data["SleepStaging"].unique()
siniflar_kodlanmis = pd.DataFrame(data.SleepStaging.factorize()[0])[0].unique()

siniflar_map = dict(zip(siniflar_kodlanmis, siniflar_kodlanmamis))

data["SleepStaging"] = data.SleepStaging.factorize()[0]
```

This is how i am trying to do it using Dask,

```
data['SleepStaging'] = pd.Series(data.SleepStaging.compute().factorize()[0])
```

But i am getting the error : ValueError: Not all divisions are known, can't align partitions. Please use `set_index` to set the index.

If I do this, I need to divide the data I made in pandas into 6000x19 data in Dask.
I am doing diving the data in pandas like this:

```
data_tum = []
data_siniflar = []
for k in siniflar_map:
  data_dizi = data[ data.SleepStaging == k ].to_numpy()
  for i in range(int(data_dizi.shape[0]/6000)):
    c=i+1
    dat = data_dizi[(c-1)*6000:c*6000,1:20]
    data_tum.append(dat)
    data_siniflar.append(k)

X = np.array(data_tum)
y = np.array(data_siniflar)
del data
del data_tum
del data_siniflar
```

Comment: if your data is too large to fit into memory, you shouldn't plan on moving seamlessly between dask.dataframe, pandas, numpy, and python objects like lists. you will have to spend time significantly restructuring your workflow to use [dask_ml](https://ml.dask.org/). start off by reading in your files to a single dask daraframe, e.g. `df = dd.read_parquet([f"{data_dir}/{f}.parquet" for f in ['1', '2', '3', '5','37','19','47','35']])`, and then start shifting to dask-ml operations rather than in-memory ones.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado thanks for the comment. I will do it the way you suggest. But how can i factorize my class column using dask i am getting the error: ValueError: Not all divisions are known, can't align partitions. Please use `set_index` to set the index.

Comment: you can't. you're going to have to get to know the dask.dataframe API and ML tools. The closest equivalent is to use `categorize` and then the `.cat.codes` attribute on the columns after categorization. However, this will require that the columns be computed. Rather than asking how to do every step in your workflow, I'd approach your problem from scratch and try to find the dask-ml native way of tackling the problem. what is it that you're trying to do? if this is a classification problem, take a look at the dask-ml docs on classifiers.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado Thank you, yes i am trying to do CNN classification using Tensorflow and Keras. I will search how to use dask in machine learning and deep learning.